# ID malformed error when reading custom folder via Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

GET /users/mailbox@server.com/mailFolders/Inbox/messages

works fine.

When I want to read a specific folder I get the id of the folder via

Get-MailboxFolderStatistics -Identity mailbox@server.com | select Name, FolderId, FolderPath

But when I try

GET /users/mailbox@server.com/mailFolders/FolderId/messages

I get the following error message:

{"error":{"code":"ErrorInvalidIdMalformed","message":"Id is malformed."}}

Do I need to translate the ID?
Is there a command for that?

Answer (score 0):

What Get-MailboxFolderStatistics returns is what is the owaId in EWS, the Graph can translateId's https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-translateexchangeids?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http but can't translate an id in that format. You can however extract the HexEntryId (prEntryId) from the owaId converting it from Base64 and removing the padding then you need to re-encode it as Base64safeurl and you should be able to then translate it eg here is an example using the Graph PowerShell SDK

```
$MailboxName = "blah@domain.com"
Connect-ExchangeOnline
$Folders = Get-MailboxFolderStatistics -Identity $MailboxName  | select Name, FolderId, FolderPath

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web 
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes Mail.Read

$HexEntryId = [System.BitConverter]::ToString([Convert]::FromBase64String($Folders[0].FolderId.ToString())).Replace("-","").Substring(2)  
$HexEntryId =  $HexEntryId.SubString(0,($HexEntryId.Length-2))

$FolderIdBytes = [byte[]]::new($HexEntryId.Length / 2)

For($i=0; $i -lt $HexEntryId.Length; $i+=2){
    $FolderIdBytes[$i/2] = [convert]::ToByte($HexEntryId.Substring($i, 2), 16)
}

$FolderIdToConvert = [System.Web.HttpServerUtility]::UrlTokenEncode($FolderIdBytes)

$ConvertRequest = @"
{
    "inputIds" : [
    "$FolderIdToConvert"
    ],
    "sourceIdType": "entryId",
    "targetIdType": "restId"
}
"@

$ConvertResult =  Invoke-MgGraphRequest -Method POST -Uri https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/translateExchangeIds -Body $ConvertRequest
return Get-MgUserMailFolder -UserId $MailboxName -MailFolderId  $ConvertResult.Value.targetId
```

Comment: Thanks for that, if I try to run it I get the following message, even if I try it on my own mailbox: "{"error":{"code":"ErrorAccessDenied","message":"Access is denied. Check credentials and try again."}}
At line:29 char:19"

Comment: the only permssion you need for translateexchangeId is User.Read while its not specific in Connect-mggraph it should be returned. You can try to execute it manually line by line and check the context you connect to eg use Get-MgContext it maybe your not connecting to the expected tenant (so you can fix that by specifying the tenantid when usingc connect-mggraph